# wordpress search form sql query

Tags: mysql, forms, wordpress

I am trying to build a custom search `form` that will query my `wordpress DB` for the results.
The problems I seem to encounter is that the form does not send anything to function upon action just says `404 not found`.

The function to query the database is located at `functions/theme-search.php` and I have declared `function search_db` in it.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

View this part of code. This isn't bulletproof, but I am  assuming the first `WP_Query call` is for the search

```
function my_posts_request_filter($input)
{
    if ( is_search() && isset($_GET['s'])) {
        global $wpdb;

        // Make your sql code

        remove_filter('posts_request','my_posts_request_filter');
    }
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how can I paginate my search results and how to turn each search result into a post of it's own?
I am trying several things but so far unsuccessful.
Maybe with this part of your code?
remove_filter('posts_request','my_posts_request_filter');